# Parse string timezone in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, datetime-format

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[('20230728 09:30:00 US/Eastern', 194.7, 195.26)]
```

I am using this list to create a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    received_historic_data, columns=["time", "open", "close"]
).set_index("time")
```

I want to convert the `Index` from dtype `object` (e.g. string) to a `datetime`.

I used this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

But pandas can't parse the string timezone "US/Eastern".

How do I parse this string to a datetime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

    
received_historic_data = [("20230728 09:30:00 US/Eastern", 194.7, 195.26),
                          ("20230729 09:30:00 US/Eastern", 195.26, 200.45),
                          ("20230730 09:30:00 US/Eastern", 200.45, 176.34)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=received_historic_data, columns=["time", "open", "close"])
```

Code using .split() .cat() .drop():

```
df[["date", "time", "tz"]] = df["time"].str.split(" ", expand=True)
df = (df
      .assign(time=pd.to_datetime(df.pop("date").str.cat(df["time"], sep=" ")))
      .set_index("time")
      .drop(columns="tz"))
print(df)
```

Code using .split() .apply() .join():

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"].str.split(" ").str[:2].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x)))
df = df.set_index("time")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       open   close
time                           
2023-07-28 09:30:00  194.70  195.26
2023-07-29 09:30:00  195.26  200.45
2023-07-30 09:30:00  200.45  176.34
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, an explicitly specified time format `'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` is required when converting to datetime.

Test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytz

# check if 'US/Eastern' is a recognizable time zone name 
print(f"{'US/Eastern' in pytz.all_timezones = }")

# prepare test data
received_historic_data = [('20230728 09:30:00 US/Eastern', 194.7, 195.26)]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    received_historic_data, columns=["time", "open", "close"]
).set_index("time")

# check the index before an attempt to transform it to datetime
print(f'''Before transformation: 
      {df.index.dtype = }
      {df.index[0] = !r}''')

# explicitly pass format when transforming to datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z')

# check the transformed index's value and type
print(f'''After: 
      {df.index.dtype = }
      {df.index[0] = !r}''')
```

My output:

```
'US/Eastern' in pytz.all_timezones = True
Before transformation: 
      df.index.dtype = dtype('O')
      df.index[0] = '20230728 09:30:00 US/Eastern'
After: 
      df.index.dtype = datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
      df.index[0] = Timestamp('2023-07-28 09:30:00-0400', tz='US/Eastern')
```

Details about:

- [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
- [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime)

Versions of the tools used:

```
python : 3.11 
pandas : 1.5.1
pytz   : 2022.5
```